# How do I toggle the text colour of an html element when it is clicked?

Tags: html, text, colors, toggle

I want to change the colour of an html element when it is clicked. I don't want the text itself to change, just the colour. The colour should toggle back and forth with subsequent clicks. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have working example:

```js
let flag = true
function toggleColor() {
  const exampleStyle = document.getElementById("example").style
  flag ? exampleStyle.color = "red" : exampleStyle.color = "blue"
  flag = !flag
}
```

```html
<div id="example" onclick="toggleColor()">your text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to toggle color of font then use:

```
var h1=document.querySelector("h1");
var iscolor=true;
h1.addEventListener("click",function(){
if (iscolor){
h1.style.color="yellow";
iscolor=false;}
else{h1.style.color="black";
iscolor=true;
}

 });
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. How does your code relate to my html tags?

Comment: This is JavaScript. You can type above code in <script> ...code....</script>. then it works. More, You will write your html tag/id/class instead of h1 in first line. like, var element=document.queryselector("html tag/id/class");

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the simple scenario your solution should look similar to this

```
var element = document.querySelector('your-element-selector');

element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   element.style.backgroundColor = 'wanted color';
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Is this html or css? I can't get it to work in my html document.

Comment: It's javascript. You can insert it into your html page just wrap the code into a script tag and place at the end of a page
Something like this:
<script>
code
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Simply use javascript:

```
<span id="demo" onclick="clicked()">your text</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function clicked() {
          document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, it works well, but I need the text to toggle back to the original colour if it is clicked again - sorry, i should have made this clear.

Comment: So you want to create toggle system?

Comment: Hi, yes that's right. The solution from cccn above works but I am interested in any other solutions also. Thanks :-)